# How can I make Jenkins not ask for re-login when there is a change from HTTPS to HTTP?

Tags: http, jenkins, https, hudson

My Jenkins instance is on **HTTPS**.

One of the plugins creates a link which is on **HTTP**.

So, whenever I click that link (frequently accessed link), Jenkins asks me to re-login which is counter-productive.

How can I tell Jenkins to relax this check and let me access that HTTP link without needing to re-login?

Comment: Is your Jenkins behind a Loadbalancer/reverse proxy by any chance?

Comment: @Pankaj No. It isn't.

Comment: ok and what you got in "Jenkins URL" under Global configuration?

Comment: https://hudsonci.oraclecorp.com/jenkins/machineabc/

Comment: What if you specify the https URL of your Jenkins here; does your above said plugin still gives you a http url?

Comment: @Pankaj This solved my problem. Can you please post this as an answer? I shall accept it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: sure, done :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the JENKINS_URL to https URL of you Jenkins i.e. under Manage Jenkins > Global Configuration. The plugin should give you an https URL now.